# SQL update to restore accidental changes

Tags: sql, database

I have a table employee type 2 scd table

```
Employee:
Id Name   from_date    to_date     current_ind
1 Rohit   2011-01-06   2019-02-01    N
1 Rohit   2019-02-02   9999-12-31    Y
2 Virat   2008-01-01   9999-12-31    Y
3 Gill    2020-01-15   9999-12-31    Y
4 Mahi    2004-05-07   2011-02-01    N
4 Mahi    2011-02-02   9999-12-31    Y
5 Ajay    2022-01-15   9999-12-31    Y
```

Somebody has updated this table incorrectly/accidentally and the table is now as below:

```
Id Name   from_date    to_date     current_ind
1 Rohit   2011-01-06   2019-02-01    N
1 Rohit   2019-02-02   2023-07-18    N
2 Virat   2008-01-01   2023-07-18    N
3 Gill    2020-01-15   2023-07-18    N
4 Mahi    2004-05-07   2011-02-01    N
4 Mahi    2011-02-02   2023-07-18    N
5 Ajay    2022-01-15   2023-07-18    N
```

The data is commited. There is no audit table.
How do I correct this data using update Update sql statement?
Write a sql update to correct this data ?

Comment: You need a `UPDATE` with the correct values - **one for each affected row**.

For example, `UPDATE tbl SET to_date='2023-07-18', ind='Y' WHERE Id=1 AND Name='Rohit'`. This is **assuming that Id, Name is a primary key**. If they aren't, then after painstakingly fixing the data, you also need to plan a proper primary key assignment.

But, before that, **you need to set up a backup/restore policy**. Maybe an auditing/undo trail too (that's more difficult).

If you *no longer have* all the correct data - and no current backups - then sorry, **your data is lost**.

Comment: If there are 1 million records? How do I write a generic update query?

Comment: Update to what? How do you know the old values?

Comment: Phony values (like 9999-12-31) tend to cause problems sooner or later. I try to avoid them.

Comment: Do you have another table with the CORRECT values? Add that definition to the question. Otherwise, take a look at @PKey's solution; chances are that it might work, **if and only if** all the changed tables had current_ind Y and to_date 9999-12-31.

Answer (score 0):

If it's SCD2, you could delete the newest that is Current_Ind = 'Y' assuming those are incorrectly inserted there.

Then you need to figure out which rows to Current_Ind = 'Y' again. When you set Current_ind to 'Y' you also set to_date to maxdate.

Easiest way to figure wich to update is to do something like this:

```
Update e
Set e.to_date = '9999-12-31',Current_ind = 'Y'
--Select * 
from Employee e
Inner join 
(Select Id, MAX(from_Date)
from Employee
group by id) emax
on e.id = emax.id and e.from_date = emax.from_date
```

This assumes that the correct rows have the news date in the from_date column, that they normally have in a SCD2 table.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your example correctly the incorrect change was: updating all the rows with `to_date = 9999-12-31 and current_ind = Y` to  `to_date = 2023-07-18 and current_ind = N`.

In that case a simple

```
update employee set to_date = '9999-12-31',current_ind ='Y' where to_date = '2023-07-18' and current_ind = 'N'
```

will do. Make sure though, that there are no real/correct rows with `to_date = '2023-07-18' and current_ind = 'N'`.

Also, some databases have *Flashback* capabilities, for example in *oracle* one could do

```
select * from employee AS OF TIMESTAMP SYSDATE - 1/24;
```

to see how the table looked 1 hour before.

(You do not mention your database - so it is unclear if you could use this feature)

Comment: And which dbms is this for, you didn't mention it.

Comment: @jarlh Didn't I? The first part is ANSI, the second as I mentioned is for Orcale

Comment: Well, an ANSI SQL date literal looks like `DATE'2023-07-18'`.

Comment: @jarlh ok, you can consider both parts Oralce stile ;-)  However it is not clear form OPs post which dbms are we talking about, also are those columns dates or strings.. etc..  Vague questions cannot get exact answers.